# you have no oracle client installed on toad

Tags: oracle, toad

i have installed oracle 11g enterprise edition(11.2.0.1.1) 64bit  on my laptop and i also installed toad for oracle xpert version 9.7.2.5.but when i try to use toad i get an error "you dont have any oracle home installed" and "you have no oracle client installed".i run sqlplus through my cmd and it work properly,i am using window 10 64bit..can anyone help.

Comment: restart your pc

Answer (score 5):

Toad 9.7 is 32-bit. It requires a 32-bit Oracle client and you have a 64-bit client installed. You can have a 32 and 64-bit Oracle client installed side by side without issue.